# How to ignore specific files in a GitHub Pull Request while merging into a later branch?

Tags: github, gitignore, pull-request

We have 4 branches in a GitHub repository, each for a different environment: DEV, TEST, UAT, and PROD.

Each branch has its own config (environment-related) files which are only valid in that branch. These files differ in different branches.

Is there any way to not include those files while merging into the later environment branch?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.  Git does not offer the ability to exclude files from merging in this way.

Git uses the merge machinery to do many different things, including rebases.  In a rebase or cherry-pick, the sides of a merge (ours and theirs) are reversed.  Consequently, any functionality that Git had that always merged from our side or their side will be broken when doing a cherry-pick or rebase.  There are numerous other reasons why this approach won't work and hasn't been implemented and they can be found by searching the Git list archives.

In general, the way you want to handle this is to include all of the files in every branch and then use some method (usually a script or build process) to decide which one to copy as the active (gitignored) file.  Oftentimes the environment will be specified based on the hostname or an environment variable and the correct file can be easily selected by a script.